# How to properly implement multiple dbcontexts, I which to make changes in multiple databases in one request

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity

The issue i'm having with this method is that all the changes are in all the databases instead of just in the selected one.

Is there a method to remove all changes or keep the changes in the correct context?

```
    private readonly MainContext _mainContext;
    private readonly List<IMultipleContext> _context = new List<IMultipleContext>();

    public UnitOfWork(
        MainContext mainContext
        MultipleContext1 multipleContext1, 
        MultipleContext2 multipleContext2, 
        MultipleContext3 multipleContext3)
    {
        this._mainContext = mainContext;
        _context.Add(multipleContext1);
        _context.Add(multipleContext2);
        _context.Add(multipleContext3);
    }

    public void SaveChanges(int index)
    {
        _context[(int)index].SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The question implies that you have a different database for each DbContext? A DbContext is not the same as a database. A DbContext exposes all or part of the underlying database, You can have multiple DbContext's exposing different, possibly overlapping parts of the same database.

Comment: I guess if my question was clear I wouldn't have the problem, I have 3 identical databases which fit on the same Context interface. however the current implementation makes all the changes stay even when i want to save another indexed database